# MKMapView is not calling delegate method

Tags: ipad, annotations, mkmapview

I am trying to drop pins on map but it is not calling delegate method

> - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation{

My app is universal so when i am using iPhone then it calls delegate method properly but when i use iPad then delegate method is not called.
code is given below:

> - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation{
>
>   static NSString *identifier = @"MachineLocation";
>     if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MachineLocation class]]) {
>
>   ```
>   MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
>   if (annotationView == nil) {
>       annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
>   } else {
>       annotationView.annotation = annotation;
>   }
>
>   annotationView.enabled = YES;
>   annotationView.canShowCallout = YES; //        
>   if (isWeatherOn) {
>       if (imageFlag == 0) {
>           annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Clouds.png"];
>       }
>       if (imageFlag == 1) {
>           annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sun + Clouds.png"];
>       }
>       if (imageFlag == 2) {
>           annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sun.png"];
>       }
>       imageFlag++;
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrest.png"];
>       NSLog(@"annotation");
>   }
>
>   annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
>
>   return annotationView;
>   ```
>
>   }
>
>   return nil;        }

under viewWillApear code is this

```
NSString *tempString;
            for(NSMutableArray *array in appDelegate.globalVehicleInfoArray) { 
                for (VehicleInfo *vehicleInfo in array) {
                    for (WeatherCondition *weather in appDelegate.globalWeatherConditionArray) {
                        if ([weather.weatherID isEqualToString:[vehicleInfo vehicleID]]) {
                            tempString = [weather weatherTempC];
                            //                            NSLog(@"weather id matched");
                        }
                    }
                    NSString *name = [vehicleInfo vehicleName];
                    NSString *machineDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@     %@ C", [vehicleInfo vehicleLastUpdate], tempString];
                    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
                    coordinate.latitude = [[vehicleInfo vehicleLastPositionY] doubleValue]; 
                    coordinate.longitude = [[vehicleInfo vehicleLastPositionX] doubleValue];
                    NSLog(@"%f , %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
                    MachineLocation *location = [[MachineLocation alloc] initWithId:[vehicleInfo vehicleID] :name description:machineDescription coordinate:coordinate];
//                    annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
                    [self.mapView addAnnotation:location];
                }


            }
```

Comment: Do you use a separate xib for iPad?  Is the map view in the xib or created programmatically?  Is the delegate outlet connected properly in the xib for the iPad?  On iPad, in viewWillAppear, does it actually go through the loop and add annotations?  Do the annotations appear as red pins?

Comment: I am getting the same error, did you manage to find the reason?

Comment: I managed it by making a new class and writing there the same code again. It works for me